# Create data in xml from txt file

Tags: xml, delphi, nativexml

I want to creat this xml file from a txt file...

i do this
Code:

```
 FXml := TNativeXml.CreateName('Root');
 FXml.XmlFormat := xfReadable;
 open the file
 AssignFile(TFile,'user.txt');
 Reset(TFile);
 while not eof(TFile) do 
 begin
    Readln(TFile,text);
    r :=  Pos(' ',text);
    t2 := Trim(Copy(text,1,Length(text)));
    t1 := Trim(Copy(t2,0,r));
    FXml.Root.NodeNew('row');
    FXml.Root.NodeByName('row').WriteAttributeString('user',t2);
    FXml.Root.NodeByName('row').WriteAttributeString('pin',t1);
 end;
   FXml.SaveToFile('new.xml');
 FXml.free;
```

something i do wrong with nodebyname but what...

Thank you...

Comment: You're reading a line from the text file into a variable called 'text', but then you check for the first blank in a non-initialised variable called 't2'. It looks like the 'r:= pos' and 't2:= trim' lines are in the wrong order.

Comment: Also: Trim(Copy(t2,0,r)); The 0 should be  a 1 for delphi strings.

Comment: Sorry about that i correct this ... the lines now is in correct order..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your text file contains more than one line, you are creating multiple nodes with the name "row". NodeByName will always return the first node with the given name.

You should store the result of NodeNew in a local variable of type TXmlNode and use that one to set the attributes.

```
var
  node: TXmlNode
...
node := FXml.Root.NodeNew('row');
node.WriteAttributeString('user',t2);
node.WriteAttributeString('pin',t1);
```

Comment: Yes my text file contains at least 3000 users and pins... Yes this works ok... thank you